# Possible error in audit in First Post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-audits

While reviewing First Posts, I was given the question at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21886917. I flagged this for moderator intervention to be moved to Math Overflow. I believe that I was wrongly audited. Please see the screenshot.

Pardon me if I am being stupid.[image: Screenshot showing that I failed the audit.]

Comment: Wanna explain why you think this belongs on MathOverflow?

Comment: Sorry, I have generally met with only programming questions on SO. I thought this was purely mathematical; I mean that it was not shown in the context of any programming. So...

Comment: @GauravJoseph That's not what makes it on topic for Math Overflow though, they are for "research level math questions," which this is no where close to being.

Answer (score 8):

While that question might also fit on different sites on the network, it also fits on Stack Overflow. There's no specific reason it's off-topic here.

Not doing anything/upvoting is the appropriate response. There's no reason to migrate questions that might fit a little better on a different site but are also on-topic here. You should only flag if the question doesn't fit on this site, but fits well on a different site.